# Correctness of product of densities representing parts of information as prior density in Bayes inference

Tags: bayesian, inference, prior

suppose I've got data $X$ from a model driven by parameter $\theta$. Model of data is represented by conditional density (likelihood function)
$$f(x|\theta).$$
Suppose the prior density of $\theta$ is denoted by
$$f(\theta).$$
My question is, is it consistent with bayesian theory to choose ANY probability density as a prior density in our model, if it's correctly defined density with respect to correct measure? I'm asking this question because I have a complicated model with 2 types of information about parameter $\theta$, and both those sources of informations have probability density as their description. I don't have an idea how to add those two sources of prior information to model, other than multiply those 2 individual densities into one and normalize them. But something inside me is telling me that might be fundamentally incorrect.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you have two candidate priors $f_1(\theta)$ and $f_2(\theta)$ which you think could both reasonably serve as the prior for $\theta$. One approach would be to define a mixture: define a new variable $z$ which takes values $0$ or $1$ only, and define a bernoulli(0.5) prior on $z$. Then, define $f(\theta|z) = z f_1(\theta)+ (1-z) f_2(\theta)$, and $f(\theta)=sum_z f(\theta|z)f(z)$. This approach gives a high probability to values of $\theta$ that are likely according to $f_1$ OR $f_2$, whereas the product of priors approach is $f_1$ AND $f_2$.

Comment: Your approach is suitable in case that those priors $f_1(\theta)$ and $f_2(\theta)$ are candidate priors. In my case I need to incorporate both of the informations of $f_1(\theta)$ and $f_2(\theta)$ into my prior density. I have a requirement for $\theta$ that has high probability in $f_1(\theta)$ and also $f_2(\theta)$. In case of misunderstanding I will describe the problem I am dealing with more accurately and concretely.

Comment: If you want $\theta$ to have high probability wrt both $f_1$ AND $f_2$, multiplying these densities is indeed the way to go. The math I would lean on to justify this is that the product of two integrable functions is also integrable.

Comment: A geometric mixture would generalise the product.